# Asp.net mvc identity SecurityStamp signout everywhere

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

What I want to do is to limit a user ID to only being able to log in to one device at a time. For example, user ID "abc" logs in to their computer. User ID "abc" now tries to log in from their phone. What I want to happen is to kill the session on their computer.

I'm using Asp.net mvc identity membership and using   SecurityStamp for this purpose.  This is my code in Account/Login action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);
```

According to the `UpdateSecurityStampAsync` method doc says : Generate a new security stamp for a user, used for SignOutEverywhere functionality. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to enable instant invalidation of cookies on other devices, then every request must hit the database to validate the cookie. To do that you need to configure cookie invalidation in Auth.Config.cs and set validateInterval to 0:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.             
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                .OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }            
);
```

Comment: Yes. Its an extra database hit on every request

Comment: try UpdateSecurityStampAsync before PasswordSignInAsync

Comment: You cant log out or on other devices user is not getting logout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107024/discussion-between-tmg-and-ucnobi-ucnobi).

Comment: tmg when i set validateInterval to 0 it logs out users very quickly

Comment: In less than 10 minutes for example

Comment: did you try to add an ExpireTimeSpan?

Comment: I've add  ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45),

Comment: ApplicationCookie deleted