# One connection per client by user

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

How is the best approach to ensure that an user has only on connection/authorization per client? Control if he can or not access that client?

Example: Like if log in mobile 1 and after in mobile 2, mobile 1 will be offline.

Comment: Token/Session revocation?

Comment: @Tseng Yes, and deny access

Comment: Identity sign-out-everywhere is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151800/asp-net-mvc-identity-securitystamp-signout-everywhere

Comment: Thanks @Tratcher! But the same will happen with tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Bearer tokens? Those are harder as the server usually relies on the built in expiration. You'd have to cross check the user ID against an activity database on each request.